# Services files are not auto reloaded in grails 3.1.6

Tags: grails, grails-3.1

I have a Groovy service `ReportService.groovy` inside `grails-app/services`.

When I make some changes in the file, console output is:

> File /home/username/project/grails-app/services/com/company/ReportService.groovy changed, recompiling...
>   Spring Loaded: Cannot reload new version of com.company.ReportService
>   Reason: Interfaces changed from [groovy/lang/GroovyObject, grails/artefact/Service, grails/events/Events$Trait$FieldHelper] to [grails/artefact/Service, grails/plugins/mail/SendMail, grails/plugins/mail/SendMail$Trait$FieldHelper, grails/events/Events$Trait$FieldHelper, groovy/lang/GroovyObject]

Hence, the changes are not seen immediately. And, I have to restart the application again and again to view the changes.

How can I view the reloading effect immediately in the application for Service classes?

Similar case was reported as issue but for java classes only.
(https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9047)

Comment: Hi @sgiri, you have this problem on every edit, or only when you change something specific? E.g. if you change a variable assignment, you have this?

Comment: @lifeisfoo Problem is in every edits. If I edit a Service which implements `WebAttributes` from `grails.web.api` package, I get this message `Reason: Interfaces changed from [grails/web/api/WebAttributes, groovy/lang/GroovyObject, grails/web/api/WebAttributes$Trait$FieldHelper, grails/artefact/Service, grails/events/Events$Trait$FieldHelper] to [grails/web/api/WebAttributes, grails/web/api/WebAttributes$Trait$FieldHelper, grails/artefact/Service, grails/plugins/mail/SendMail, grails/plugins/mail/SendMail$Trait$FieldHelper, grails/events/Events$Trait$FieldHelper, groovy/lang/GroovyObject]`

Comment: Is this only happening with the service that `implements WebAttributes`? Or do you have the same issue with your other normal services (that don't `implement` anything)?

Comment: @Ian for normal services as well.

Answer (score 1):

This was a known bug around grails 3.1.5 - 3.1.7.  It has been fixed since grails 3.1.8.  Also, for auto-reloading to work, you have to be using the 'development' environment via the grails run-app command.

Comment: Would you be able to provide any JIRA tickets for the Grails framework that show this? (not that I don't trust you, just so we can see the details)